# Creating pandas.DataFrame from numpy.array

Tags: python, pandas

Here's what I'm working with:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.__version__  # '1.8.1'
pd.__version__  # '0.14.1-107-g381a289'
```

Here is some fake data:

```
foo = np.arange(5)
bar = np.random.randn(30).reshape((5, 3, 2))
```

I want to get `foo` and `bar` into a `pd.DataFrame`. 
To my surprise, the following doesn't work (even though `foo.shape[0] == bar.shape[0]`):

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(foo=foo, bar=bar))
# Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

This does work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(foo=foo.tolist(), bar=bar.tolist()))
df['bar'] = df['bar'].apply(np.array)
```

This roundabout method of converting my `array` to a nested `list` and then converting it back to an array via `apply` is bothersome. Is there a more straightforward way that I'm just not aware of?

Comment: DataFrames aren't really meant to have lists of lists as elements.  Is your working `df` really what you want?

Comment: @DSM: what I want is a DataFrame with one column of integers and one column of 2-d numpy arrays.

Comment: I don't think that's a supported use case for DataFrames; while you can cram nonscalar data into a cell, there's not much you can do with it after that.  You'll have a column dtype of object, which is slow to begin with, and you can't really do any fast aggregation ops, so you'll have to fall back to relatively slow apply ops.  Depending on preference you might be more interested in using a MultiIndex or a Panel instead of this approach.

Comment: speed is not a huge issue for me; I'm typically working with 2k - 40k rows. pd.Panel is not a viable option because of the mixed dimensionality of the columns; I've only shown two columns here, but I have many more with 1, 2, or 3 dimensional data in each cell. I guess the lesson here is that I can't think of pandas DataFrames as being good for the same use cases as data.frames in R.

Comment: @drammock Did you find a solution for that?

Comment: @Varlor the approach I wrote into the question itself works, after a fashion. I don't think I ever found anything better (though admittedly it was 4.5 years ago; at this point I don't even remember what project the question relates to)